# ffmpeg watermark transparent background

Tags: php, ffmpeg, watermark

I'm trying to add a watermark to a video file but i'm having problems with the background of the watermark because i want it to be transparent.

My approach is like this: i make a png file the size of the video with transparent background like this

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 
$almostblack = imagecolorallocate($im,254,254,254); 
imagefill($im,0,0,$almostblack); 
$black = imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,0); 
imagecolortransparent($im,$almostblack); 

$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);

// Write the string at the top left
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, 'Hello world!', $textcolor);

imagepng($im, $img);
imagedestroy($im);
```

and then i add it to the video like this

```
exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i '$file->path' -sameq -vf 'movie=$img [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h [out]' '$new_path'");
```

the watermark is added but it's background is not transparent.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong ?

UPDATE: it turns out it works just fine for other png images so the problem must be in the way i build the png file any ideas why it doesn't work that way ?

Comment: Ditch the scripting and try to get ffmpeg working first. Please update your question with the actual ffmpeg command and the complete console output. Also, [`-sameq` does not mean "same quality"](http://superuser.com/a/478550/110524) and should not be used (it has been removed from ffmpeg). You do not need to use `movie` for overlay: `ffmpeg -i video -i image -filter_complex overlay ... output`.

Comment: the image is attached to the video the problem is that the background of the image is not transparent it makes it white.
also ffmpeg does not return any error
i've made some more tests since i asked the question and it turns out that for other png works just fine.
so the problem must be in the way i'm making the png image

Comment: The console output would have shown useful information about the png input.